# SpringBoot Kafka: Clarification on consumer initiated transactions

Tags: spring-boot, jdbc, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-transactions

[This link tells us](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1699#issuecomment-775222536) to use @Transactional for 1PC between a DB and Kafka for consumer-initiated transactions.

An excerpt:

> the container (configured with a KTM) starts the kakfa transaction

The question is where and how do we configure a container with the KTM? Looked at the [code sample here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#ex-jdbc-sync) and it seems that the configuration for producer has it configured for transactions:

```
spring.kafka.producer.transaction-id-prefix=tx-
```

However, imagine that we do not have the producer or any event generation to kafka in the listener as in:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "group1", topics = "topic1")
    @Transactional("dstm")
    public void listen1(String in) {
        // COMMENT THIS:
        // this.kafkaTemplate.send("topic2", in.toUpperCase());
        this.jdbcTemplate.execute("insert into mytable (data) values ('" + in + "')");
    }
```

Now the questions is:

1. if the kafka transaction is in play?
2. Would the offsets commit (for the message "in") not happen if the db transaction is rolled back?
3. Do I need to manually ack for the offsets?

Comment: Ideally, you don't do this at all. Use Kafka Connect JDBC sink rather than Spring JDBC Template

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions).

For consumer-initiated transactions, the listener container must be configured with a `KafkaTransactionManager` so the offset can be sent to the transaction.

If you are not sending data to `Kafka` it makes no sense to use a consumer initiated transaction. Normal Spring transaction management will apply and if the commit fails, the normal container error handling will handle the exception (normally re-seek the record and retry).

If you are consuming and sending to `Kafka` then the container must start the Kafka transaction, not the producer; otherwise the send won't be rolled back.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that from the docs that only the Spring tx mgmt will apply. And  DB tx will be committed before the kafka messages are ack. Please correct me if needed. Also, another reason for asking this question is that we do see Kafka transactions being started. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/74946915/3109248

Comment: Boot will automatically configure a `KafkaTransactionManager` when you set the transaction id prefix. In addition, if Boot finds a `KTM`, it will automatically wire it into the container factory. To prevent a kafka transaction from being started, you could force the TM to null in the container properties (after boot has done the auto config), or don't use boot to set the `transaction-id-prefix`; instead use `spring.kafka.producer.properties.transactional.id=prefix`. That will still work for producer-only transactions, but will bypass Boot's auto configuration logic for the container.