# spring kafka: Transactions in consumer Timeout expired after 60000 milliseconds while awaiting AddOffsetsToTxn

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

We have a transactional **producer**. And there are no issue there.

For the **consumer**, we see the following in the logs. Question is why is a transaction being started here while we are consuming the message (and there is this resulting exception)?

```
2022-12-28 18:02:05.986 DEBUG  [qa] 85474 --- [tainer#0-51-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          :  Creating new transaction with name [null]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2022-12-28 18:02:10.437 DEBUG  [qa] 85474 --- [tainer#0-51-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          :  Created Kafka transaction on producer [CloseSafeProducer [delegate=brave.kafka.clients.TracingProducer@43e18a26]]
2022-12-28 18:02:10.438 DEBUG  [qa] 85474 --- [tainer#0-51-C-1] abc.abc.kafka                 :  NORMAL uid[n/a] cid[uPRwhWZikfcYpGfIqh7TxXFnm6VmZWkf] m[[S] Consuming message] data[record = ConsumerRecord(topic =XXXXXXX)))]
2022-12-28 18:02:10.438 DEBUG  [qa] 85474 --- [tainer#0-51-C-1] abc.abc.kafka                 :  NORMAL uid[n/a] cid[uPRwhWZikfcYpGfIqh7TxXFnm6VmZWkf] m[Processed message]

2022-12-28 18:03:10.439  INFO  [qa] 85474 --- [tainer#0-51-C-1] abc.abc.common.Generic                   :  NORMAL uid[n/a] cid[uPRwhWZikfcYpGfIqh7TxXFnm6VmZWkf] m[Throwable t] data[exception = [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@6d314e1d] ex[Timeout expired after 60000 milliseconds while awaiting AddOffsetsToTxn] sts[org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000 milliseconds while awaiting AddOffsetsToTxn
]
2022-12-28 18:03:10.439 DEBUG  [qa] 85474 --- [tainer#0-51-C-1] abc.abc.kafka                 :  NORMAL uid[n/a] cid[uPRwhWZikfcYpGfIqh7TxXFnm6VmZWkf] m[[E] Consuming message]
2022-12-28 18:03:10.439 DEBUG  [qa] 85474 --- [tainer#0-51-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          :  Initiating transaction commit
2022-12-28 18:04:10.444 ERROR  [qa] 85474 --- [tainer#0-51-C-1] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000 milliseconds while awaiting EndTxn(true)
 commitTransaction failed: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=brave.kafka.clients.TracingProducer@43e18a26]
2022-12-28 18:04:10.444 DEBUG  [qa] 85474 --- [tainer#0-51-C-1] o.s.k.t.KafkaTransactionManager          : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000 milliseconds while awaiting EndTxn(true)
 Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
2022-12-28 18:04:10.445  WARN  [qa] 85474 --- [tainer#0-51-C-1] o.s.k.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory   :  Error during some operation; producer removed from cache: CloseSafeProducer [delegate=brave.kafka.clients.TracingProducer@43e18a26]
2022-12-28 18:04:12.436 ERROR  [qa] 85474 --- [tainer#0-51-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000 milliseconds while awaiting EndTxn(true)
 Transaction rolled back
```

This is the **configuration**:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: indb-prop
      auto-index-creation: false
  kafka:
    producer:
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer
      retries: 2
      client-id: ${spring.application.name}-${info.cluster}-${IP_ADDRESS}PP
      transaction-id-prefix: tx-${spring.kafka.producer.client-id}-
      properties:
        enable.idempotence: true
        spring.json.add.type.headers: false
      bootstrap-servers:  ${kafka_bootstrap_servers_2}
#    listener:
#      missing-topics-fatal: true
#      type: batch
#      concurrency: 15
#      ack-mode: manual_immediate
#      poll-timeout: 1s
    consumer:
      key-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      group-id: ${spring.application.name}-${info.cluster}-111111111112
      client-id: ${spring.application.name}-${info.cluster}-${IP_ADDRESS}
#      client-id: ${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}-${IP_ADDRESS}
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      enable-auto-commit: false
      isolation-level: read_committed
#      max-poll-records: 3
      fetch-max-wait: 5s
      properties:
        max.poll.interval.ms: 20000000
        spring.json.trusted.packages: '*'
        spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        spring.json.value.default.type: net.abc.abc.EventData
      bootstrap-servers: ${kafka_bootstrap_servers}
```

And the **consumer**:

```
@KafkaListener(
        topics = "SOME_TOPIC",
        autoStartup = "true")
// @Transactional(transactionManager = "mongoTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@Override
public void onMessage(ConsumerRecord<String, EventData> data) {

    if (data == null || data.value() == null) {
        return;
    }

    logger.debug(m -> m.event(KAFKA)
            .msg("[S] Consuming message")
            .with("record", data));

    try {

        logger.debug(m -> m.event(KAFKA)
                .msg("Processed message"));
    }
    finally {
        logger.debug(m -> m.event(KAFKA)
                .msg("[E] Consuming message"));

    }
```

The springBoot version: '2.6.6'

Answer (score 0):

How many broker nodes are you using?  If 1, have you overridden the broker params KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR and KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR to 1?

Similar sounding issue here:
https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/1816

Rob.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Rob. Thanks. the issue is that transactions are fine on the producer side. However transactions are started on the consumer as well even though there is no event being generated to Kafka on that end.

Comment: Can you create a super simple cut down project on git demonstrating the issue, and I will take a look?